Who thinks Grothendieck was the greatest?
As background, I will state that I am appalled when people have arguments about who, in any field, is the GOAT. Brady vs Bradshaw, Biles vs Comaneci, etc. To me it makes no sense to talk about "the" greatest, and one should limit oneself to saying, at most, so-and-so is/was "one of the greatest".
Anyway, with that said, I note that Wikipedia writes of Grothendieck, "He is considered by many to be the greatest mathematician of the twentieth century," referring to obituaries in the Guardian and by David Mumford which make this precise claim.  No similar claim appears in the Wikipedia articles about possible competitors, such as Von Neumann, Godel, Turing, Erdos, or André Weil. They are not even apotheosised as being "one of the greatest."  So Wikipedia describes Von Neumann as having "the widest coverage of any mathematician of his time," Godel as being "one of the most significant logicians in history", Turing as "widely considered to be the father of theoretical computer science", Erdos as as "one of the most prolific mathematicians and producers of mathematical conjectures of the 20th century", and Weil as "one of the most influential mathematicians of the twentieth century".
Now I remark that  "he is considered by many" is a kind of cheat, and unfairly passes the buck, because one does not say who considers it - it could be anyone.  So my question is, what prominent mathematicians or mathematical historians, if any, have gone on record and said they thought or think that Grothendieck was the greatest mathematician of the 20th century?

First of all, himself. This he wrote in his book "Recoltes et semailes".  But I have also heard this from other top mathematicians (will not give their names), so Wikipedia statement is correct.

I cite Recoltes et semailes: “It would seem that, as a servant of a vast unifying vision born in me, I am ‘one of a kind’ in the history of mathematics from its origin to the present day.”

Peter Scholze previously said in an interview with a German newspaper that Grothendieck was his role model. Pierre René Deligne, a disciple of Grothendieck, also said Grothendieck was his role model in his book on IHES. However, none of them called Grothendieck the greatest mathematician of the 20th century. At the same time, Pierre René Deligne said in an interview with a YouTuber that there is no way to rank mathematicians linearly. Maybe, it is not an exaggeration to say that Grothendieck was one of the greatest mathematicians of the 20th century, but obviously it seems strange to call Grothendieck the only one. As you said, it is possible that it is an exaggeration. And it probably comes from the special nature of Grothendieck's life.
However note that, as Deligne said, it seems quite strange to rank mathematicians linearly, but some mathematicians nevertheless have ranked other mathematicians. Weil said that Siegel was the greatest mathematician of the 20th century, and Atiyah said that the greatest mathematician of his generation was probably Serre, and Serre said in an interview with a media outlet around 2010 that Deligne was the greatest mathematician in existence now.

Weil, Serre, Deligne, Scholze, Grothendieck, Dieudonné... these are all people who praised each other. Do you know who was a truly important mathematician of the 20th century? Robert Henry Risch, the author of the algorithm for solving integrals that we have all been using for decades. If all of Grothendieck's works were to disappear suddenly, my life wouldn't change at all, but without Risch algorithm, maybe my life would change a bit.

@M. Lonardi, how did they praise each other? When did Weil, Serre, Grothendieck, Dieudonne praise Scholze?

@MBN Besides the fact that Serre is still alive and has surely praised Scholze, bringing the circle to a close, I barely know their names. For me, they are the mathematical equivalents of Picasso, Fontana, Mondrian... When I was younger, I didn't understand what the genius of their paintings consisted of and thought I was stupid; then I realized that the secret lies in making others believe you are a genius. In this Picasso and Grothendieck were masters, unlike Risch, whom I mentioned as the opposite example (an unknown person who accomplished something useful instead of intellectual fluff).

As far as I know Dieudonné DID rank mathematicians linearily, as absurd as it can be !

I will not upvote this answer unless it gives sources for at least some of its strangely precise-vague claims ("a media outlet around 2010", "an interview with a YouTuber", and what is "Deligne's book on IHES"?).

Please see https://www.simonsfoundation.org/2012/06/19/pierre-deligne/ and https://youtu.be/ZY9EdTA0X7M?feature=shared. But Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any books on IHES other than translations written in my native language. If you can overcome the language barrier, please read it. https://m.yes24.com/Goods/Detail/14091284
